# Should the escaped fragment URL or the hash bang URL be used with Fetch as Google in Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, url, ajax

which one url must be added into url input field of Google search console-> Crawl->Fetch as Google?

```
example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=my-ajax-page
```

or

```
example.com/#!my-ajax-page
```

Comment: Whichever is the public URL that the user sees. (Although you can naturally submit either to the tool whilst testing?) However, note that [Google deprecated this AJAX crawling method in 2015](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification).